# resolved IDA I get a warning "7687F932: Microsoft C++ exception (exc.code e06d7363, tid 15160)"

Tags: ida

when trying to debug an application with IDA, I get the following warning:
7687F932: Microsoft C++ exception (exc.code e06d7363, tid 15160)

After clicking Ok, I am taken to the kernelbase.dll line

below I attach pictures of whats going on

[image][image]

Im relatively new to IDA so your support would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This means that the program threw a C++ exception. These are usually not fatal, but IDA will break whenever they occur unless you manually disable this behaviour: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1414.shtml. You should be able to continue execution whenever such an exception occurs.